# How can I automatically merge two different schemas in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL database in production (I'll call it db1) with lots of data already.

In dev, I made several changes to it's structure and added data for testing purposes. I'll call it db2.

I need to merge db2's schema into db1's without losing any db1's data and without copying data from db2.

Is there any way to do this **automatically** (using scripts, procedures or some Workbench's built-in functionality)?

Comment: If the databases are on the same server then you could simply generate a differential result set and then insert that to db1.

Comment: This is why you need migrations. All database schema changes should be done via scripts, whether it be a programming script/language or a plain SQL file. You then need to track which scripts have already been run, so that the next time you need to run them you won't run them again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Dump the schema you need without data with mysqldump --no-data
2. Load the dump into the new database.
3. Create a stored procedure with Dynamic SQL and a cursor over information schema.tables. Basically, for each table that belongs to the original database, construct an INSERT ... SELECT query that inserts the data into the new database. 
   Notice that you may need to lock out the entire database with LOCK TABLES statement if you want to prevent data from being modified while you're copying it. You can construct LOCK TABLES statement with Dynamic SQL as well.
4. Done.

If step 3 looks complicated, you could INSERT... SELECT data manually.
There is no automatic way to do it in MySQL: depending on the changes you made to the original schema, e.g. added columns/indexes/changed field types, a different INSERT...SELECT query may be needed.

Comment: I don't need the new data from db2. I just need it's structure (which is db1's on steroids).

Comment: Regardless of the question, your answer provides insight on handling schema changes.